# changing format of date to different format

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am using mysql, I have a column in table called date_1 which is varchar(255), the column consist of dates

which are in format 'June 25, 2014' I want to convert them to '25-06-2014' ie DD-MM-YYYY

how to do that?

Comment: As a side note, storing dates as varchar is not a good design at all.

Comment: I convert database from sql server to my sql, first i need to clean it then i will convert it into date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_1, '%M %e,%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') AS new_date
```

See [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for all of the format specifiers that can be used with these functions.

FYI, you should store dates as actual dates in your database as it is a native format in MySQL which means you then have a lot of tools available to you to make working with them easier. This includes converting them to any format you want upon retrieval and also sorting and searching them.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is not to store them as a varchar and instead store them in their native format as a `date` or `datetime`. You then have a rich selection of operators to format them in any way you can think up easily and support rich query operations on the column.